# I don't have a center constraint: Fixed leading and trailing constraints with a center constraint may cause clipping

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, uisegmentedcontrol

```
Fixed leading and trailing constraints with a center constraint may cause clipping.
```

But I don't ***have*** a center constraint. Here is the `UISegmentedControl` that I'm using:

[image]

Below are my constraints. Trailing and leading space, height, bottom space, top space.

[image]

I imagine that it's complaining that if the screen was really narrow and the localized text was long that it might cut things off, but it's that going to be true for every segmented control?